# Parallels Plesk MySql Database

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, plesk, parallels

Who to download mySQL Database(Full or part of them) from Parallel Plesk Server running latest Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit + Plesk 12.0 through a MacBook Terminal(SSH). The Plesk server only allow mySQL from local host.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's remote databases access setting. if you enable "Allow remote connection from any host" then you can access your databases from all IP's. But you need to enable mysql port in server firewall if you want to allow remote mysql access on your server.

Comment: Is it possible from SSH or SFTP? Mod security as Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump your database over ssh and later download it with ftp/sftp.

Create a MySQL-Dump:

```
mysqldump -u [YOURUSER] -p'[YOURPASSWORD]' [YOURDATABASE] > /your/path/
```

Make sure you replace /your/path with a Directory you have access with sftp to.
(Keep in mind that it may be necassary to adjust the file-permissions)

Or Dump it to /var/www/vhosts/[YOURSITE]/[HTTP ROOT DIR] and download it via http(s).

Answer (score 0):

Plesk is shipped with phpMyAdmin, so you can access it from Plesk > Subscriptions > example.com > Databases > phpMyAdmin and create a database dump from there.